# Git Builder not authenticating with Github in CloudBuild

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I am using a CloudBuild file designed for a Microservices Monorepo project.

The code runs a bash script using the Git builder to determine which directories within the Monorepo have had changed commited to them. This should output a text file containing the names of each directory where a change was made in the last commit, for use in later pipeline steps. See below for an excerpt from the code:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    args: 
    - -c
    - |
      git fetch --depth=2 origin main
      echo hello
      git  log
      git --no-pager diff --name-only HEAD^ HEAD | grep "/" | cut -d/ -f1 | sort | uniq > /workspace/diff.txt
```

When running this code on a private repository, the following error is given on the `git fetch --depth=2 origin-main` line:

`fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address`

The CloudBuild agent was successfully able to clone the repo in a previous step, as I can confirm in my build logs. I believe this is an issue with the Git builder not being given the same OAuth token as the main CloudBuild agent. I have tried using different CloudBuilder service accounts with different levels of permissions with no success. Any suggestions for this would be appreciated.

#### Resources

The above excerpt is taken from the below article and repository:

- https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-cloudbuild-build-specific-micro-services-in-a-monorepo-63a7f961ac63
- https://github.com/ajiteshk/MicroServicesCI-In-MonoRepo

There is an existing issue relating to this error, with no solution at the time of writing:

- https://github.com/ajiteshk/MicroServicesCI-In-MonoRepo/issues/1

Comment: Look at  you command: How the system can know the credential to use? You load a git container, you perform git command. Where do you get the credential? Nowhere, therefore, it can't work! In addition, you can't reuse the Cloud Build service configuration, inside the Cloud Build runtime, it's 2 different things. The solution here, is to put your credentials (a token?) in Secret Manager and to load/read/use them in your git commands.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Perhaps you could clarify for me, as I must be misunderstanding the documentation somewhere. The Git builder container uses the credentials of the builder service account for the GCP project (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/git#readme). When a Github host is connected to the GCP project, an OAuth token is stored in Secret Manager, which is used by the builder service account (https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/github/connect-repo-github#connecting_a_github_host see step 6). (1/2)

Comment: The builder service is able to clone the repository into the container, but unable to use the credentials in the Git container like the documentation says it should. Have I made a mistake somewhere? (2/2)

Comment: Ok, let me explain. Imagine your door is locked. You have the key. But you don't use it to open the door. Will it be open??? Obviously not. It's the same thing here: your current service account maybe has the token (the key) and the permission to use it, but if you don't use it, you can't have access!

Answer (score 2):

Historically, the credentials used by Cloud Build to clone the repository have not been available to users for use in `cloudbuild.yaml` steps.

You have two options:

- [set up SSH keys](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/access-github-from-build) to access your private repository
- use the [2nd gen repositories](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/github/connect-repo-github?generation=2nd-gen) [API](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.connections.repositories/accessReadToken) to fetch the credentials used by Cloud Build and use these. git really ought to set up with this by Cloud Build, but it isn't set up this way right now. You can still get the credentials with the following command: `curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v2/projects/PROJECT-ID/locations/REGION/connections/CONNECTION/repositories/REPOSITORY:accessReadToken`.

Comment: Good usage of the GCP API however the curl needs to use POST with an empty body. Correct curl needs -x POST option.

Comment: It's more -X POST to be added not -x POST (mind the capital X)